# Как много файлов записать в json файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, файлы

Есть папка `files`, в ней файлов и мне надо их записать в `json`.

Как улучшить скрипт, чтобы можно было из папки взять все файлы и записать в json?

```
import json

a = open('one.cfg', 'r')
b = open('two.cfg', 'r')

data = {
   'one.cfg' : a.read(),
   'two.cfg' : b.read(),
}

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос, собственно?

Comment: @gil9red Вопрос в том как сделать данную операцию только с большим количестве файлов я ж не буду каждый файл прописывать

Comment: Например, через `glob`, можно получить список файлов: `import glob file_names = glob.glob('files/*.*')`

Comment: os.walk и куча других способов обхода каталогов. Ваш вопрос про это, а не про JSON

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо большое я понял вас я нашел решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если подправить пример в вопросе, то выйдет что-то такое:

```
import glob
import json

data = dict()
for file_name in glob.glob('files/*.*'):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        data[file_name] = f.read()

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```